# upload image to facebook wall after posting it to photos using sharekit 2.0

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sharekit

I'm trying to post image to facebook photos using sharekit:

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image_ title:@""];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

Everything works fine but normally when you post photo using facebook website information is posted on faceook's wall also. When I post my photo using sharekit it doesn't happen. How can I achieve this?